# D3.js numbers spirally outwards from inner wheel

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I worked in the d3 library and created nested wheels. I have no idea how to add texts into the wheel, spirally from inside out. The number starting point doesn't matter, and numbers must spirally outwards according the previous position.

**Codes**

```
let allAxis = (data.map(function(i, j) {
    return i.name
  })),
  total = allAxis.length,
  radius = Math.min(options.width / 2, options.height / 2),
  angleSlice = Math.PI * 2 / total,
  Format = d3.format('');

let rScale = d3.scale.linear()
  .domain([0, options.circles.maxValue])
  .range([50, radius]);

let svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", options.width + options.margins.left + options.margins.right)
  .attr("height", options.height + options.margins.top + options.margins.bottom);

let g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + (options.width / 2 + options.margins.left) + "," + (options.height / 2 + options.margins.top) + ")");

let axisGrid = g.append("g")
  .attr("class", "axisWraper");

let axis = axisGrid.selectAll(".axis")
  .data(allAxis)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .attr("class", "axis")

//append them lines
axis.append("line")
  .attr("x1", 0)
  .attr("y1", 0)
  .attr("x2", function(d, i) {
    let tempX2 = radius * Math.cos(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    return tempX2;
  })
  .attr("y2", function(d, i) {

    let tempY = radius * Math.sin(angleSlice * i - Math.PI / 2);
    return tempY;
  })
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill", "none");

//Draw background circles
axisGrid.selectAll(".levels")
  .data([12,11,10,9,8,7,6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1])
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("class", function(d, i) {
    return `gridCircle-${d}`
  })
  .attr("r", function(d, i) {
    return parseInt(radius / options.circles.levels * d, 10);
  })
  .attr("stroke", "black")
  .attr("fill-opacity", function(d, i) {
    return options.circles.opacity;
  });

axisGrid.select(".gridCircle-1").attr("fill-opacity", 1);
axisGrid.select(".gridCircle-2").attr("fill-opacity", 1);
```

**Expected Result**

[image: Nested Spirally Number Wheel]

---

**Updated #1 (with PointRadial)**

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/arcanabliss/8yjacdoz/73/

Answer (score 1):

You need [`pointRadial`](https://github.com/d3/d3-shape#pointRadial):

> Returns the point [x, y] for the given angle in radians, with 0 at -y
> (12 o’clock) and positive angles proceeding clockwise, and the given
> radius.

You can play around with the example below in order to fit to your arrangement e.g. in order to start from 3 o'clock and rotate counter-clockwise etc you just need to play with `degrees` and `radius`:

```
const degrees = (i % numbersPerRing) * (360 / numbersPerRing);
const radius = (Math.floor(i / numbersPerRing) + 1) * ringSize;
```

```js
// numbers
const numbersPerRing = 8;
const ringSize = 30;
const originX = 120;
const originY = 120;
const numbers = [... new Array(18)].map((d, i) => i + 1);
const diameters = [... new Array(4)].map((d, i) => (i * ringSize) + 10);

const points = numbers.map((n, i) => {
  const degrees = (i % numbersPerRing) * (360 / numbersPerRing);
  const radius = (Math.floor(i / numbersPerRing) + 1) * ringSize;
  const point = d3.pointRadial(degrees * (Math.PI / 180), radius);
  return {
    "value": n,
    "degrees": degrees,
    "point": point
  }
});

// svg
const svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", originX * 2)
  .attr("height", originY * 2);  

// circles
svg.selectAll("circles")
  .data(diameters)
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", originX)
  .attr("cy", originY)
  .attr("r", d => d)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "#aaaaaa");

// labels
svg.selectAll("labels")
  .data(points)
  .enter()
  .append("text")
  .attr("x", (d, i) => d.point[0])
  .attr("y", (d, i) => d.point[1])
  .attr("transform", `translate(${originX},${originX})`)
  .attr("text-anchor", (d) => (d.degrees > 180) ? "end" : "start")
  .text(d => d.value);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
```